# combining filters in Google Earth Engine from feature collection

Tags: python, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I don't think I have seen this asked and unfortunately this is probably a simple answer that I am getting stuck with.

I have a feature collection and I am simply trying to filter two properties from that feature collection simultaneously.  The feature collections are a list of projects located across the USA and so I am trying to visually display two such projects at the same time.  I have no problem filtering one of the projects out of the feature collection and displaying it in Google Earth Engine but I am having trouble trying to filter a second project area and display it at the same time as the first project area.

My code in Python 3 Jupyter Notebook looks like this (of course after having initialized GEE and so on)

I tried using Filter.and based on the notes from GEE which states to use and as a way to grab multiple filtered information but I must be doing something wrong so below is what I tried at first but this didnt work.

How can I rewrite this to properly grab the two projects from the FeatureCollection at the same time?

Thanks in advance for the help and the time.

```
fc = (
ee.FeatureCollection("File location here")
.filter('PROJ A == "PROJECT NAME"')
.filter('PROJ B == "PROJECT MAME"')
)

# Draw the visualization

wtmap = geemap.Map()
# set our initial map parameters for USA
center_lat = 40
center_lon = -100
zoomlevel = 5

# Initialize the map
wtmap = geemap.Map(center = [center_lat, center_lon], zoom = zoomlevel)
wtmap.add_basemap("SATELLITE")
wtmap.addLayer(fc)
wtmap.addLayerControl()
wtmap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the function `ee.Filter.And`:

```py
# FeatureCollection
listOfFeatures = [
  ee.Feature(None, {'PROJ A': 'PROJECT NAME', 'PROJ B': 'PROJECT NAME'}),
  ee.Feature(None, {'PROJ A': 'PROJECT', 'PROJ B': 'NAME'})
]
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(listOfFeatures)

fcsubset = fc.filter(ee.Filter.And(
    ee.Filter.eq('PROJ A', 'PROJECT NAME'),
    ee.Filter.eq('PROJ B', 'PROJECT NAME')
))
```

Inside the GEE Python API, as @Mutewinter mentioned [in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/374396), the `help(ee.Filter)` command shows the available methods for `ee.Filter`:

> And(*args)
> Combine two or more filters using boolean AND
> Or(*args)
> Combine two or more filters using boolean OR.

Note the capital letters in `And`/`Or` methods.

I hope this answer helps you.